# Every possible combos for an island in Hashi game

Tags: php, algorithm

Here's the game : [Hashiwokakero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero).

To solve it, I need to find all possible combinations of links + islands around every island.

Constraints are, 1 or 2 links, and one combination is enough links created for the targeted island.

For example, I have a island `['A' => 3]`, which means it needs 3 links to be solved, and it has 3 neighbors `['B', 'C', 'D']`.

I'd like to find an algorithm which would produce such an array :

```
[
    ['B' => 1, 'C' => 1, 'D' => 1],
    ['B' => 1, 'C' => 2],
    ['B' => 1, 'D' => 2],
    ['B' => 2, 'C' => 1],
    ['B' => 2, 'D' => 1],
    ['C' => 1, 'D' => 2],
    ['C' => 2, 'D' => 1]
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want us to solve your homework, maybe you could at least describe it a bit better so that we don't have to research the rules of the game you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you think you need to create those combinations? I think it's easiest to have vertices (each vertice can have 1 to 4 neighbours) and links between neighbours with weights element {0,1,2}. The sum of the links has to match the vertice. Many links can be added by simple rules. For the rest you can use backtracking. You have to make sure to remove links which are crossed when you add a link.

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I talked about the game to give context. This is not a homework. I'm only looking for another way to implement this logic. My question only focused on finding every combination possible with neighbors. Easy solving, path crossing, back tracking are not the subject of the question. All elements required to answer are in the question, the link is only for the curious and to answer 'why do you need to do this ?'.

Comment: @maraca I need these combinations for backtracking purposes. So that I can loop on combinations, try one and if it fails try the second one etc, recursively on every island.

Comment: Yes I see, but think about it, it would only work for the first node. The following nodes have restrictions like connections not possible any more because they were crossed by others added earlier or they already have one or two connections in a direction.

Comment: Not if the grid updates on every recursive call, and combinations are calculated in each recursive step :) so the second island would calculate its possible combinations depending on what already happened with the first island !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all combinations of links (0, 1, or 2) per neighbor, with a fixed total number of links, then you could use the following recursive function:

```
function getPossibleLinks($value, $neighbors) { 
    if ($value == 0) return [[]];
    $max = min(2, $value);
    $min = 2 - min(count($neighbors) * 2 - $value, 2);
    if ($min > 2) {
        throw new Exception('Not possible to assign that many links');
    }
    $results = [];
    for ($count = $min; $count <= $max; $count++) {
        $nextResults = getPossibleLinks($value - $count, array_slice($neighbors, 0, -1));
        foreach($nextResults as $result) {
            if ($count) $result[end($neighbors)] = $count;
            $results[] = $result; 
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

You would need to pass it the number of links as first argument (`$value`), and the array of neighbors as an array of strings.

Here is an example call:

```
$results = getPossibleLinks(3, ["B", "C", "D"]);
```

After this call, `$results` will have this content:

```
[
    ['B' => 2, 'C' => 1],
    ['B' => 1, 'C' => 2],
    ['B' => 2, 'D' => 1],
    ['B' => 1, 'C' => 1, 'D' => 1],
    ['C' => 2, 'D' => 1],
    ['B' => 1, 'D' => 2],
    ['C' => 1, 'D' => 2]
]
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/811582).